# NVD3 Multibar default preselect certain bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Im currently using NVD3 JS library to plot a multibar chart. I wish to "preselect" certain bar values, so it will only display certain bars by default. Following chart shows what i want to achieve:
[image]
Where:

```
"Data 3 " is by default **not** selected
"Data 0 " is by default selected
"Data 1 " is by default selected
"Data 2 " is by default selected
```

I have the above sample created in Fiddle (As per @shabeer90 suggested below): http://jsfiddle.net/gxc27jav/3/

Comment: Could you add your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), someone could have a proper look on the problem

Comment: Uh oh... i think i found an answer in Stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25955603/nvd3-multibar-chart-toggle-default-values-to-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add a "disabled" attribute to the series object for the series you want to be disabled... example:

```
[{disabled: true, values: [...]}, {values: [...]}]
```

Comment: I found the answer prior to yours. But no harm accepting your's as the answer :)